# Automatically Sync Files between two Ubuntu Servers on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

I am running two or more Ubuntu Servers on Amazon EC2. They are all connected to an Elastic Load Balancer so all of the files on each server must be the same. Is there a way that I can just SFTP files to one Ubuntu server and have the files automatically sync across all servers?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Linux System Administration. There's darn near as many ways to do this as stars in the sky. Pick one and dig through it and then look at some others and figure out which works best for your particular needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many synchronization methods or distributed file system solutions out there.  Take a look at [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and its friends for some of the most common sync methods.  [GlusterFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS) is a common distributed NAS/filestore solution.